# Specialization of STL Templates

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, visual-c++, stl

I am trying to write high-performance code that uses random numbers, using Mersenne Twister. It takes roughly `~5ns` to generate a random `unsigned long long`. This is used to generate a `double`, however, these take `~40ns` to generate in a distribution.

Viewing the STL code the `double`s, generated by a distribution, are generated by calls to `std::generate_canonical`, which involves a `std::ceil` and `std::log2` operation, I believe it is these that are costly.

These operations are unnecessary as they are used to calculate the number of bits needed for calls to any RNG implementation. As this is known before compile time, I have written my own implementation that does not make these calls, and the time to generate a `double` is `~15ns`.

Is it possible to specialize a templated STL function? If so how is this achieved, my attempts so far result in the original function still being used. I would like to specialize this STL function as I would still like to use the distributions in `<random>`.

This is in Visual C++, though once the code has been developed it will be run on **Linux** and use either GCC or ICC. If the method for generating doubles on Linux is different, (and quicker), this problem is irrelevant.

Edit 1:

I believe all distributions requiring a double make calls to `std::generate_canonical`, this function creates a double in the range [0,1) and the correct precision is created by iteratively adding calls to the RNG `operator()`. The `log2` and `ceil` are used to calculate the number of iterations.

MSVC `std::generate_canonical`

```
// FUNCTION TEMPLATE generate_canonical
template<class _Real,
size_t _Bits,
class _Gen>
_Real generate_canonical(_Gen& _Gx)
{   // build a floating-point value from random sequence
_RNG_REQUIRE_REALTYPE(generate_canonical, _Real);

const size_t _Digits = static_cast<size_t>(numeric_limits<_Real>::digits);
const size_t _Minbits = _Digits < _Bits ? _Digits : _Bits;

const _Real _Gxmin = static_cast<_Real>((_Gx.min)());
const _Real _Gxmax = static_cast<_Real>((_Gx.max)());
const _Real _Rx = (_Gxmax - _Gxmin) + static_cast<_Real>(1);

const int _Ceil = static_cast<int>(_STD ceil(
    static_cast<_Real>(_Minbits) / _STD log2(_Rx)));
const int _Kx = _Ceil < 1 ? 1 : _Ceil;

_Real _Ans = static_cast<_Real>(0);
_Real _Factor = static_cast<_Real>(1);

for (int _Idx = 0; _Idx < _Kx; ++_Idx)
    {   // add in another set of bits
    _Ans += (static_cast<_Real>(_Gx()) - _Gxmin) * _Factor;
    _Factor *= _Rx;
    }

return (_Ans / _Factor);
}
```

My Simplified Version

```
template<size_t _Bits>
double generate_canonical(std::mt19937_64& _Gx)
{   // build a floating-point value from random sequence
    const double _Gxmin = static_cast<double>((_Gx.min)());
    const double _Gxmax = static_cast<double>((_Gx.max)());
    const double _Rx = (_Gxmax - _Gxmin) + static_cast<double>(1);

    double _Ans = (static_cast<double>(_Gx()) - _Gxmin);

    return (_Ans / _Rx);
}
```

This function is written in `namespace std {}`

Edit 2:

I found a solution please see my answer below.

Comment: Please provide minimum code to show your problem

Comment: Why not just wrap your code in a new [distribution object](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomNumberDistribution)?

Comment: You can specialize a standard template but you are only allowed to so so for your own custom types, not built in ones.

Comment: In linux you dont use Visual C++ compiler, check if he problem remains there with e.g. GCC or Clang

Comment: @JorgeBellón: Why not? Visual C++ targets Linux nowadays.

Comment: Usually in STD function and types used are templatized, so you can replace a function instead of specializing it. Again show minimum code (for example what you would want to achieve).

Comment: Added sample code, also [GCC STL source](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/3052e4ec519e4f5456ab63f4954ae098524316ce/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/random.tcc#L3318) shows a similar implementation involving `log`. I may implement my own distributions based on STL and use my version of `std::generate_canonical` to generate `double` values. Which was what I wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, specializing Standard Library functions is not allowed; doing so results in Undefined Behavior.

However, you can use alternative distributions; C++ has well-defined interfaces between generators and distributions.

Oh, and just to eliminate the possibility of a beginners error (since you don't show code): you **do not** create a new distribution for every number.

Comment: You can add specializations to `std` in the general case, but only if they depend on at least one of your own types.

Comment: @Quentin: True, but that's an exception to the general rule, and the exception doesn't apply here since the type here is `double`.

Comment: Yes, that's just a nitpick. Although I'm pretty sure you *can* in general, since some standard type traits explicitly state that specializing them is UB.

Comment: Could you qualify *Sorry, specializing Standard Library functions is not allowed; doing so results in Undefined Behavior.* in your answer.  Right not it reads as a blanket prohibition when it is only prohibited for built in types.

Comment: @Quentin All in all a thin wrapper around `double` could do the trick pretty easily. So that standard prohibition on specializing for built ins isn't a problem really or am I wrong?

Comment: It is specializing for `double` AND Mersenne Twister `std::mt19937_64`, I only really want this to be used if both of those criteria are met as those will be the only types I am using

Comment: @bartop +1 He can also wrap the random number generation engine into a new class through composition.

Answer (score 0):

By creating a template function with all parameters set, and declaring the functions as `inline`, it is possible to create user defined version of `std::generate_canonical`.

User defined `std::generate_canonical`:

```
namespace std {
    template<>
    inline double generate_canonical<double, static_cast<size_t>(-1), std::mt19937>(std::mt19937& _Gx)
    {   // build a floating-point value from random sequence
        const double _Gxmin = static_cast<double>((_Gx.min)());
        const double _Rx = (static_cast<double>((_Gx.max)()) - _Gxmin) + static_cast<double>(1);

        double _Ans = (static_cast<double>(_Gx()) - _Gxmin);
        _Ans += (static_cast<double>(_Gx()) - _Gxmin) *_Rx;

        return (_Ans / _Rx * _Rx);
    }

    template<>
    inline double generate_canonical<double, static_cast<size_t>(-1), std::mt19937_64>(std::mt19937_64& _Gx)
    {   // build a floating-point value from random sequence
        const double _Gxmin = static_cast<double>((_Gx.min)());
        const double _Rx = (static_cast<double>((_Gx.max)()) - _Gxmin) + static_cast<double>(1);

        return ((static_cast<double>(_Gx()) - _Gxmin) / _Rx);
    }
}
```

The second parameter `static_cast<size_t>(-1)` should be modified to whatever value is used by specific libraries, this is the case for VC++ but may be different for GCC. This means it is not portable.

This function has been defined for `std::mt19337` and `std::mt19937_64` and seems to be used for STL distributions correctly.

Results:

```
double using std::generate_canonical

Generating 400000000 doubles using standard MT took: 17625 milliseconds
This equivalent to: 44.0636 nanoseconds per value

Generating 400000000 doubles using 64bit MT took: 11958 milliseconds
This equivalent to: 29.8967 nanoseconds per value


double using new generate_canonical

Generating 400000000 doubles using standard MT took: 4843 milliseconds
This equivalent to: 12.1097 nanoseconds per value

Generating 400000000 doubles using 64bit MT took: 2645 milliseconds
This equivalent to: 6.61362 nanoseconds per value
```

Comment: Do not use `static_cast<size_t>(-1)`. It works only for 2's complement notation - it's not portable.

Comment: It is the initialization taken directly from the MSVC STL code, that is why it is being used. I believe it is different for GCC, but I have not looked that much into that aspect of the problem

Comment: @bartop: It is entirely portable. This is a cast, with well-defined behavior. The unsigned types are defined to act modulo 2^N. You're confused with the bit pattern of signed behavior, but there are no bit patterns involved here. This is defined by math.